# According to Catholic theology are the Psalms suitable preaching/prayers/songs for Christians?

Tags: catholicism, psalms

Martin Luther was a Catholic priest and notoriously anti-Jewish. The Catholics kept Jews in ghettos. The Torah was deemed a "curse". Jews were deemed the spawn of the Devil. The Psalms are largely concerned with meditations on the Torah, the plight of the nation and prayers for the retribution on their enemies. I'm wondering if and why then their songs a songs and prayers would be deemed Christian prayers. Psalm 1 for example ascribes to the Torah what Paul said comes from the breath/spirit of God. He said the law kills and was the power of [personified] sin.

> KJV Psalm 1: 1 Blessed is the man that walketh not in the counsel of
>   the ungodly, nor standeth in the way of sinners, nor sitteth in the
>   seat of the scornful.
>   2 **But his delight is in the law of the LORD; and in his law doth he
>   meditate day and night.**
>   3 And he shall be like a tree planted by the rivers of water, that
>   bringeth forth his fruit in his season; his leaf also shall not
>   wither; and whatsoever he doeth shall prosper...

In other words, are the Psalms considered Jewish-specific or deemed equally useful and relevant as prayers and songs for Christians? IE, is the first Psalm a Christian Psalm as well as a Jewish Psalm?

Comment: Your interpretation of Paul is greatly flawed. In particular, it seems to ignore the countless times Paul quoted the Psalms. Christians and Jews may interpret the Psalms differently, but l am aware of no extant Christian group that dismisses them as Jewish, and therefore not appropriate for Christians.

Comment: Luther's notorious anti-Semitism is generally considered a blight on Protestantism. Catholicism isn't too big on defending Luther or his views.  In the case of his racism most Protestants would consider it a blind spot of his as well. Why you would pick him to frame a question about Catholic theology is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

St. Thomas Aquinas writes in [his introduction](https://isidore.co/aquinas/PsalmsAquinas/ThoPs0.htm) to his [Commentary on Psalms 1-54](http://hosted.desales.edu/w4/philtheo/loughlin/ATP/index.html)*:

> The material [of the Psalms] is universal, for while the particular books of the Canon of Scripture contain special materials, this book has the general material of theology as a whole.
> …
> the work of God is fourfold; namely, that of creation, …; governance, …; reparation, …; glorification, ….
>
> There is a complete treatment of all these things in this doctrine [i.e., in the psalms].

<sup>cf. ch. 13 § "The Course on the Psalms" of Jean-Pierre Torrell, O.P.'s [*Saint Thomas Aquinas: The Person and His Work*](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/5927).</sup>

Those who pray [the traditional Divine Office](https://isidore.co/divinum/cgi-bin/horas/officium.pl) (e.g., priests and religious) pray all 150 psalms in a week.

<sup>*(cf. also [St. Robert Bellarmine's commentaries on all the psalms](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/5953))</sup>